# AnkhSVN error, looking for strange path

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

I'm using SVN via AnkhSVN for my project and whenever I go to commit I get the following error(s)[image: VN Error #1] then when I click the Stacktrace button this is what it's showing [image]. I have no idea what this path is that it's looking for, so what can I do to resolve this?

**EDIT:** This is weird because that directory has never existed, not removed or deleted either. No files appear to be in conflict either, so this one has me stimpted.

Comment: I've tried everything y'all have suggested but still cannot do a commit. I updated, then tried to commit => no go I looks for conflicts => no go. Anyone else got a solution to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN error when trying a commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207012/svn-error-when-trying-a-commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to update first, and then commit.

If that fails, please give some more information:

- What's the status of the files you're trying to commit?
- Does that path exist in the repository, or was it moved/renamed/deleted recently?
- Run `svn info` on the files you're committing, and check which of them has that 'strange path' as URL property

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a conflict.  Try to resolve the confilct first.  When you submit, scroll down the list of items until you see one in bright red.  It will be the conflict due to the path.  Uncheck all the other items first and resolve this item.  When this is rosolved, the commit will work properly.