# SVN error when trying a commit

Tags: ankhsvn

I have a project under source control and anytime I try to check in one of the solutions I get this error message [image] 
I've not got a project GlassButtons so I have no idea what SVN is looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AnkhSVN error, looking for strange path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021247/ankhsvn-error-looking-for-strange-path)

Comment: Does the rest of the path make any sense? Could it be related to a different working copy for instance? Check if the SCC Binding path in File -> Subversion -> Change Source Control is set correctly.

Comment: Also, open the properties window and the pending changes window, highlight all changes, and check the Url property for the above path. AnkhSVN doesn't commit things other than what you have checked.

Comment: Sander Rijken you're right I did double post this issue. I completely forgot about the first one so for that I apologize. I want to keep this one open (have started a bounty) and close the other one

Comment: yeah, I realized later that the other one has an answer marked as "answered", so it's essentially dead. Lets get to the real cause of it in this one! Can you try answering the questions I have?

Comment: I tried everything you have mentioned thus far and nothing has changed, and I've brought on another developer and cannot let him start until I can actually check in the project

Comment: Just a thought, but is it possible that the first part of the path `/svn/GpdsCreation...` is misspelled?  Is it supposed to be `/svn/GodsCreation...`?  Could changing this affect anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible reason is the following:
There once was a folder GlassButtons that has been added to your local working copy (SVN Add) and deleted afterwards from the disk. This will lead to the situation you encounter: AnkhSVN tries to commit that folder and therefore wants to read it from the disk, but it doesn't exist anymore, so it gives this error.
The following should help you:

- Install TortoiseSVN
- Right click on the folder ...\Helpers\Controls
- Choose SVN Commit
- In the list, uncheck everything
- In the list, look for the folder GlassButtons. It should have the "Text status" "missing"
- Check it
- Click OK

Now your working copy should be fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Should the path begin with /svn/GodsCreationTaxidermy instead of /svn/GpdsCreationTaxidermy? Looks like a simple typo to me, which explains why it can't find the path.